# Java Stream groupingBy where key is an element in a sublist

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class called `Food`:

```
public class Food {
    private Collection<FoodToFoodGroup> foodToFoodGroups;
    //getters and setters
}
```

And `FoodToFoodGroup` looks like this:

```
public class FoodToFoodGroup {
    private Food food;
    private FoodGroup foodGroup;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Finally, each `FoodGroup` has a name:

```
public class FoodGroup {
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}
```

These classes are all entities mapped via hibernate. I get a collection of all `Food` entities in the database with a call to `foodRepository.findAll()`, and I am trying to group all `Food` instances by the name of their `FoodGroup`, in order to end up with a `Map<String, Collection<Food>>`. I was attempting to do this via the Stream API, but can't come up with the way to do this using the `Collectors.groupingBy` collector.

```
Map<String, Collection<Food>> foodsByFoodGroupName = 
    foodRepository.findAll().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            //what goes here?
        ));
```

Note here that a `Food` can be in multiple `FoodGroup`s, so I would need any `Food`s that are in multiple `FoodGroup`s to show up in multiple `Collection`s in the resulting `Map`. Is this possible with the Stream API and `Collectors.groupingBy()`?

**Example**

If I have the following foods:

```
Food: Pimento Cheese
    - FoodToFoodGroups: [
        - FoodGroup: cheese,
        - FoodGroup: dairy
      ]
Food: Chocolate Milk
    - FoodToFoodGroups: [
        - FoodGroup: milk,
        - FoodGroup: dairy
      ]
```

I would want the resulting `Map` to look like this:

```
Key: cheese
    - Collection<Food>: [Pimento Cheese]
Key: milk
    - Collection<Food>: [Chocolate Milk]
Key: dairy
    - Collection<Food>: [Pimento Cheese, Chocolate Milk]
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but when `Food` has a collection of `FoodToFoodGroup`s, each `Food` seems to have multiple `FoodGroup`s, so how can you *"group all Food instances by the name of their FoodGroup"*? Which `FoodGroup` in the collection of a `Food` instance would be considered *theirs*?

Comment: With hibernate, should be easier way to maintain relationship between `Food` and `FoodGroup`. Seems like `@ManyToMany`

Comment: @MaxVollmer I've added an example to help in understanding

Comment: I think your data model has unnecessary circular references. Each `Food` could simply contain a collection of `FoodGroups`; the `FoodToFoodGroup` object seems unnecessary. It seems like you may be attempting to represent a normalized relational database table directly as an object, instead of joining the data in a structured way. Though this doesn't really affect the solution to the problem, I think it makes it semantically more difficult to discuss.

Comment: But the issue here is `Food` instance may have multiple `FoodGroup` instances. So how you are going to group such a thing?

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to align with the classes you've given. Reading your example I'd expect a class `Food` with a collection of `FoodGroup`s, not a collection of `FoodToFoodGroup`s.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I've updated the example to more accurately reflect the class structure

Comment: Now in your example the `FoodToFoodGroup`s contain **only** `FoodGroup`s, but in your code they contain `Food` and `FoodGroup`s. From context I can assume that every `FoodToFoodGroup` in the collection of a `Food` points back to the same `Food` (basically a circular reference), but that's not clear in your code. Nothing there restricts something like `FoodA` -> `FoodToFoodGroup` -> `FoodB`. Also it's still not clear **why** you have a collection of `FoodToFoodGroup`s, when the `Food` is always the parent. A collection of `FoodGroup`s would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it what you're looking for

```
foodRepository.findAll().stream()
     .map(Food::getFoodToFoodGroup)
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         f -> f.getFoodGroup().getName(),
         HashMap::new,
         Collectors.mapping(FoodToFoodGroup::getFood, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Perfect! That `Collectors.mapping` is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `groupingBy` is what you want here, since it is not designed for putting the same item in multiple groups.

For a not-purely-functional solution using streams, you could flat-map each `Food` to a `foodGroupToFood` entry set, then add all of the pairs to a map using a `BiConsumer`.

```
BiConsumer<Map<FoodGroup, Set<Food>>, Map.Entry<FoodGroup, Food>> addEntryToMapOfSets = (map, entry) -> {
    if (map.containsKey(entry.key()))
        map.get(entry.key()).add(entry.value());
    else
        foodGroupToFoods.put(entry.key(), Stream.of(entry.value()).collect(Collectors.toSet()))
};
Map<String, Collection<Food>> foodGroupToFoods = new HashMap<>();
foods.stream()
  .flatMap(food -> food.getFoodToFoodGroup().stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair.foodGroup, pair -> pair.food))
       .entrySet())
  .forEach(entry -> addEntryToMapofSets(foodGroupToFoods, entry));
```

Disclaimer: I haven't written in Java in a while, please correct my usage of Streams API if it needs correction. 
Edit: This is probably more complicated than it needs to be.